# I can’t use sprintf()

Tags: c, casting, printf

I want to cast `int` to `char`.
This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
        int i = 7;
        char *s;
        sprintf(s,"sprint f = %d",i);
        printf("printf s = [%s]",s); 
}
```

It ends `Segmentation fault`.
What’s wrong is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have any memory allocated for `s`. It's just a pointer that is either NULL or pointing to a random location (depending on the compiler). Trying to write to it is like going to bed without caring where you are - and the probability that you've just broken into someone else's house is way larger than randomly selecting your own bed. Thus, Segmentation Fault - the computer's way of getting your program arrested.

To allocate the memory, you can either let the compiler set some aside for you (`char s[22]`), or allocate your own (`char *s = malloc(22)`).

Comment: I added `s = malloc(sizeof(int));`. Then It works well.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` is kind of random -- it probably allocates 4 bytes, which is big enough for `7` but not big enough for larger numbers.  You want `malloc(12)` for enough space to hold any 32-bit int.

Comment: What does the size of an `int` have to do with the number of characters (and trailing NULL) he is trying to `sprintf()` into the string?

Comment: Yeah, while the answer is basically correct, using sizeof(int) is not.  The maximum length number you can get is presumably 11 characters, big enough to hold -2147483648.  And, of course, you need to add space for the "boilerplate" in the format string.  I make it out to be that you need to allocate at least 22 bytes.

Comment: @HotLicks: Doh, not enough coffee. You're, of course, correct.

Answer (score 1):

`s` is an invalid pointer - therefore you can't write to the memory it points to (if any), nor can you read from it. Allocate memory for it:

```
char s[64];
```

or

```
char* s = malloc(64);
```

Comment: I can't compile when I change to this way. `error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[64]’ from type ‘void *’`

Comment: @user1345414 don't reassing the array, I was just presenting 2 options.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore I was wrong. I retied your way and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Code needs *memory* to `sprintf()` the data.

With some embedded apps, I need to be lean, yet tolerant of `int` as 16, 32 or potentially 64 bit, so to right-size the buffer:

```
static const char *format[] = "sprint f = %d";

// Size `s` to be sufficiently large as format and int size may change.
char s[sizeof format + sizeof(int)*3 + 3];

sprintf(s, format, i);
printf("printf s = [%s]",s);
```

I like using the `sizeof(some_integer_type)*3 + 3` to account for the memory needed for all sorts on integer types.

(Note: Cheating as I assume `CHAR_BIT == 8`)